# How to write If else condition in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file to take backups . I was able to write it  but need help with writing a condition in my batch file.

Step 1:

```
Zip %Output_Path%\ Apps_backup_%today%.zip \\%Server%\QlikViewfolder\Common\apps\*.qvw

Zip %Output_Path%\Gen_backup_%today%.zip \\%Server%\QlikViewfolder\Common\generators\*.*
```

Step 2:

```
Zip %Output_Path%\Daily_backup_%today%.zip %Output_Path%
```

Step 3:

```
del \\New folder location\*.zip
```

Step4:

```
Move %Output_Path%\Daily_backup_%today%.zip to  \\New folder location
```

My question: I want to give an condition before step 3 that , deletion in step 3 should take place only if step 2 has completed successfully. How do I do that?

Comment: Hint: - [Errorlevel](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) - Almost all applications and utilities will set an exit code when they complete/terminate.

Comment: Besides of %errorlevel% you can use pipeline operators || and &&, exactly like in the other, better OS.

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/if.html